# Using font-family and a src URL in @font-face rule isn't showing the font

Tags: html, css, web

Face font doesn't load a font I downloaded and placed in the same folder as my website.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontName';
    src: url('font.ttf');
}

header {
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'fontName';
```

I did change the ttf file name, but I don't think that is the issue as it didn't work on another font I tried.

Are there any errors in my code?

Answer (score -1):

The `.ttf` file format is not enough on its own, you have to specify its `format` as well (as seen in the provided CSS), as well as the `font-family` must be the determined according to the font's title, for example: "font_Name_regular".

And the following formats are also needed:

- WOFF
- WOFF2
- EOT Lite or EOT Compressed
- and SVG

for the text to appear in a **cross-browser** way (in most browser environments).

You can generate them via a third-party online app, like this: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
using the "Expert..." mode, choosing all the file-formats. The more you choose the better the cross-browser compatibility will be.

Then you'll get (in a zip) something like the following:

`font-name-webfont.ttf` (which is your base file, but again, you need to be attentive about the `font-family` name, that is the "title"),

`font-name-webfont.eot`,

`font-name-webfont.svg`,

`font-name-webfont.woff`

&

`font-name-webfont.woff2`
files.
And inside the given `stylesheet.css`, you'll find the following, which is important, as said earlier:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font_Name_regular';
    src: url('font-name-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font-name-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font-name-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('font-name-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font-name-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font-name-webfont.svg#font_Name_regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Which then you can use, as desired, on your website.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've seen a bunch of people use .ttf on tutorials, but I'll try other formats.

Comment: I worked!! Thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, take a look, and decide whether to mark it as chosen. Thank you.